# Python Dictionary of List - Returning Keys which have a unique value

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dictx = {'C2': ['2', '5', '7'], 'A1': ['1','4', '5'], 'C1': ['2', '5'], 'A2': ['4', '5', '7', '8'], 'B3': ['4', '7'], 'B2': ['2', '4', '6', '7', '8']}
```

This is my dictionary. I'm trying to return:
'B2' and 'A1' preferably in a list, as these two keys have unique values. Order doesn't matter. Would love some help, as I've tried to create a large set of for loops but with no luck (such as flipping).

Side note: The values of the dictionary range from 0-9 in string form if that helps.

Edit: the 1 and 6 is confusing people, sorry - to be specific, it needs to return B2 and A1 BECAUSE they have UNIQUE values - not because they are those values.

Comment: Flipping is the way to do this.

Comment: how are you concluding that B2 and A1 has unique values?

Comment: Wording is very confusing, and I cannot edit. To make clear: A unique value is a member in a sublist such that it is not a member of any other sublist. For example, `'1'` only happens in `A1` and `'6'` only happens in `B2`. So these are "unique".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a general approach that doesn't rely on 1 and 6 being the unique values:

```
from collections import Counter
key_counter = Counter([entry for val in dictx.values() for entry in val])
print ([key for key in dictx if any(key_counter[val] == 1 for val in dictx[key])])
```

Output:

```
['A1', 'B2']
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to do it with for loops, but I suppose using Counter works a bit better =)